# pgAgent not working on Another database other than Postgres

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgagent

I'm trying to schedule a job using pgAgent in postgresql. 
pgAgent is working fine with the postgres database, but when i'm selecting the other database which i created. It is not working, the job is getting failed.

Can someone guide me in configuring it for another database also.

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

1. Find your `%AppData%\Roaming\postgresql\pgpass.conf` file under the user whose credentials you have provided for the pgAgent installer. For my computer, it's `C:\Users\postgres\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\pgpass.conf`
2. Change the line `localhost:5432:postgres:postgres:password` into `localhost:5432:*:postgres:password` (Format: HOST:PORT:DATABASE:USER:PASSWORD)

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. PgAgent --> Steps --> ConnectionType="Remote"
2. PgAgent --> Steps --> Connection string :  host=localhost port=5432 dbname=dataBaseName user=userName  password=password

Will Work..!